# Introduction to Statistical Learning Exercise 4.12(c) and (e)

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

How can we figure out coefficients of the softmax logistic regression using the coefficients from the standard logistic regression?

This is from Chapter 4 of ISLR 2nd edition.

Also, can you please help me with question (e)? I am just a poor soul going through ISLR alone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Divide both numerator and denom. to the numerator term:
$$p=\frac{1}{1+\exp((\hat\alpha_{apple,0}-\hat\alpha_{orange,0})+(\hat\alpha_{apple_1}-\hat\alpha_{orange,1})x)}$$

Basically, they're equivalent models and when fitted to the same data, they'll predict the same outcomes when trained enough. This is because the minimum is unique for logistic regression (using cross-entropy loss).